# Gradle: How to get actual module name with grouped modules

Tags: android, gradle, module, multi-module, android-multi-module

I am using a multi-modular architecture for my android app with module grouping i.e. I group my modules under a directory to make it more organised.
The structure is similar to this-

```
MyApplication
├───app
├───common
│   ├───network
│   └───presentation
...
```

Note that `common` is just a directory and not a module. Whereas, `network` and `presentation` both are android modules.

Now when I try to print the name of all the modules in `build.gradle` in either of `afterEvaluate` or `subProjects`-

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    println("Project name is: "+ project.name)
}
```

Only two module names are printed i.e. `app` and `common`.
But `common` is not really a module and the modules inside `common` are not printed as somehow gradle (or studio) doesn't understand that it's just a module group.

The main intent is to identify if the given module is an android module or just a kotlin/java module. But since gradle doesn't even list down `network` and `presentation` I am not able to identify the type of module.

How can I get all the modules listed while using grouping?

Comment: Have you included those modules in your settings.gradle file?

Comment: Also to identify whether a module is android module or kotlin/java module, you can open the build.gradle for the module and check the plugin that is applied. If it is com.android.library it is an android library, if it is com.android.application, it is an android application and if it is java-library and also org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm then it is a Kotlin library